# Toggle Text and Textbox when Checkbox is checked/unchecked using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

In my HTML program, I am trying to implement a feature where there is a text question, "Did you work out today?" followed by a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked yes, I want a new line to appear that asks, "How long did you work out?" followed by a textbox.
I currently have the CSS that sort of accomplishes my goal, but it only toggles the textbox, and How long did you work out constantly shows. How can I hide the text along with the textbox? Here is my CSS code:

```
function $_(IDS) { return document.getElementById(IDS); }
function toggle(Info) {
var CState = $_(Info);
if (CState.style.display != "none") { CState.style.display = "none"; }
                               else { CState.style.display = "inline"; }
}
function HideElem(IDS1, IDS2) {
  toggle(IDS1);
  toggle(IDS2);
}

function inputFocus(i){
    if(i.value==i.defaultValue){ i.value=""; i.style.color="#000"; }
}
function inputBlur(i){
    if(i.value==""){ i.value=i.defaultValue; i.style.color="#888"; }
}
```

And here is that implemented in HTML:

```
Did you work out today? <div class="checkboxFour">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange = "HideElem('share','meal')" id="checkboxInput" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxInput"></label>
  </div>
  <span id= "share">
    </span> <br><br>How long did you work out? <input type="text" id="meal" name="meal" size="40" style="display:none;" 
    value="Example: 8.5 Hours" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)">
```

I am also using a stylized checkbox, if that changes things. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a css style to a text node(the caption) so wrap the caption and the input element in another element and apply the visibility to that wrapper element

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="HideElem('share','mean-ct')" id="checkboxInput" name="" />
```

then

```
<span id="mean-ct" style="display:none;">
    How long did you work out?
<input type="text" id="meal" name="meal" size="40" value="Example: 8.5 Hours" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" />
</span>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ng7J3/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your question with `span` tag and specify `id` for it.Try this:

**Html:**

```
<span id="how" style="display:none;">How long did you work out? </span>
```

**javascript:**

```
if (CState.style.display != "none") { 
  CState.style.display = "none"; 
  document.getElementById("how").style.display = "none"; //hide the question
}
else { 
    CState.style.display = "inline"; 
    document.getElementById("how").style.display = "inline"; //display the question
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EW9pM/)